# Android - adb logcat without debug logs

Tags: android, adb

I don't want to see debug logs from `adb logcat` command. There are tons of debug logs from my phone and I don't want to see them.

`adb logcat --help` says `" *:I "` will output only info logs but is there any option to filter all logs except debug.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

From the [docs here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#filteringOutput), when you specify a log level filter, it will show all messages at that level and higher.  The levels are specified as:

> The tag of a log message is a short string indicating the system component from which the message originates (for > example, "View" for the view system).
>
> The priority is one of the following character values, ordered from lowest to highest priority:
>
> - V: Verbose (lowest priority)
> - D: Debug
> - I: Info
> - W: Warning
> - E: Error
> - F: Fatal
> - S: Silent (highest priority, on which nothing is ever printed)
>
> ...
>
> The following filter expression displays all log messages with priority level "warning" and higher, on all tags:
>
> ```
> adb logcat *:W
> ```

So with this in mind, passing the filter you mentioned `*:I` will log everything but Verbose and Debug logs.

Unless your intention is to show Verbose as well as the other log levels, I don't think you can do that because specifying Verbose includes anything above Verbose.

If that is the case, it might be useful for you to filter on a specific tag instead of a specific log level, or some combination of both.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are using zsh you should wrap `*:W` in single quotes, so the command should be: `adb logcat '*:W'`. ([Source](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2901))

Answer (score 23):

`adb logcat *:I` will display **all** logs with priority INFO and higher.

> The priority is one of the following character values, ordered from lowest to highest priority:
>
> - V — Verbose (lowest priority)
> - D — Debug
> - I — Info
> - W — Warning
> - E — Error
> - F — Fatal
> - S — Silent (highest priority, on which nothing is ever printed)

The above information is available in 
[Write and View Logs with Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

Comment: If this is not working, try `adb logcat '*:I'`

Answer (score 10):

If you're on **zsh** like on *Catalina OSX* instead of bash you may need to perform the following commands:

Use --- `noglob adb logcat *:E` --- replace the **E** with whatever, below.

Alternatively you can also use --- `adb logcat '*:E'` --- (quotes around)

```
V: Verbose
D: Debug
I: Info
W: Warning
E: Error
F: Fatal
S: Silent
```

The reason being that Zsh interprets the wildcard as you wanting to expand files ending in that letter without the quotes wrapping around or the noglob prefix.

Answer (score 7):

To enable logging on some **Huawei** devices:

- Dial *#*#2846579#*#*
- Select 'ProjectMenu'
- Select 'Background Setting'
- Select 'Log Setting'
- Select 'Log Switch'
- Enable 'LOG on'
- Select 'Log level setting'
- Enable 'DEBUG'
- Press the 'Back' key
- Select 'Dump and Log'
- Enable 'Open Dump and Log'
- Press 'Back' key 5 times to return to home screen.
- Reboot the phone.

LogCat should now work.

Answer (score 7):

`logcat` won't let you show Debug only but you can show Debug and higher (Debug, Info, Warning, Error, Fatal) with:

`adb logcat YourLogTag:D *:S`

The `*:S` suppresses logs from other apps.

You can pipe the result through `grep` to only show Debug:

`adb logcat YourLogTag:D *:S | grep "D YourLogTag"`

Comment: With the Oh my Zsh shell this worked for me:
`adb logcat | grep " E "`
(If you don't want to search for a Tag)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific application you are looking for eg. a flutter application
you can string the parameter commands together like `adb logcat *:s flutter:* *:w`

this states that:

`*:s` all should be silenced

`flutter:*` show everything related to "flutter"

`*:w` show all warnings and up.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a filter for a specific application using its package name.

Comment: I can do that but i want to see logs outside of my application (Like crashes etc) except those debug logs

Comment: I didn't know that - could you show how that is done please? Can I simply do that at command line?